# MQTT publishing via Python: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I've tested my script on a MQTT broker in my local network with this script:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single('some_topic, 'some message', hostname="192.168.1.123")
```

and everything works. Now I want to publish to an actual server that I was given credentials to. Sadly, all examples of paho MQTT scripts are publishing to a local server, so there is nothing I can really model my script after. The credentials I have included a username, a password, and a topic. As "hostname" I entered the website of the company's server.

The script now says

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

client = mqtt.Client()

client.username_pw_set("given_username",password="given_password")

publish.single("some_topic",'some message',hostname="example.com")
```

Sadly, I get an error.

```
  File "get_datas.py", line 18, in handle_data
    publish.single("some_topic",msg,hostname="example.com")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 223, in single
    protocol, transport)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 159, in multiple
    client.connect(hostname, port, keepalive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 962, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Did I script this wrong?

Edit:
Seems like there was a problem with the hostname. I was able to resolve this by inserting the IP address of the server, which I obtained by

```
[11:26:39] $ ping example.com
PING example.com (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from example.com (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=43.3 ms
```

Comment: Though your script seems to be correct, you need to get the correct hostname for the MQTT service running in your company & make sure that the script can reach that host name.

Comment: @cheesus if you are going to substitute host names, please use something like `example.com` then it's obvious since `website.io` actually exists

Answer (score 1):

1. You may be missing mentioning the protocol part in url like `tcp://website.io`. That should be properly mentioned for *websocket* *tcp* or *ssl*.
2. Also check for your outbound traffic rules in your firewall. `sudo ufw status` add you allow communication protocol to everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the connection to website.io:1883 (default MQTT port)

```
PS C:\> Test-NetConnection website.io -port 1883                                                                        WARNING: TCP connect to (3.220.104.187 : 1883) failed                                                                   WARNING: Ping to 3.220.104.187 failed with status: TimedOut                                                             

ComputerName           : website.io
RemoteAddress          : 3.220.104.187
RemotePort             : 1883
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
SourceAddress          : 192.168.123.165
PingSucceeded          : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

The TCP ping test failed. So are you sure that the address and port are right?

Also MQTT with SSL (Default MQTT SSL port is 8883) doesn't give a TCP response:

```
PS C:\> Test-NetConnection website.io -port 8883
WARNING: TCP connect to (3.220.104.187 : 8883) failed
WARNING: Ping to 3.220.104.187 failed with status: TimedOut


ComputerName           : website.io
RemoteAddress          : 3.220.104.187
RemotePort             : 8883
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
SourceAddress          : 192.168.123.165
PingSucceeded          : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

https://www.hivemq.com/public-mqtt-broker/ Is a public MQTT server. That one is pingable:

```
PS C:\> Test-NetConnection broker.hivemq.com -port 1883                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ComputerName     : broker.hivemq.com
RemoteAddress    : 52.29.71.7
RemotePort       : 1883
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 192.168.123.165
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

Comment: website.io is not actually the website in the script, it's a placeholder for the purpose of discretion :)

Comment: Aah right, but can you reach your MQTT server with a ping

Comment: this gave me an idea which solved my problem, thanks!